# I was confused, the class Card object cannot be set manually but successfully seted through different class

Tags: python

this is class card code

```
class Card:
"class time definetion"
SUITS = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
FACES = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']

def __init__(self, face, suit):
    self.face = face
    self.suit = suit

@property
def face(self):
    return self._face

@property
def suit(self):
    return self._suit

@property
def image_name(self):
    return str(self.suit).replace(' ', '_') + '.png'

def __repr__(self):
    return f'Card(face="{self.face}", suit="{self.suit}")'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.face} of {self.suit}'
def __format__(self, format):
    return f'{str(self):{format}}'
```

but when i tried to create an object of the class i.e

```
w = Card(Card.FACES[1], Card.SUITS[1])
```

### here's the error i get

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

in

----> 1 w = Card(Card.FACES[1], Card.SUITS[1])

in **init**(self, face, suit)

```
  5 

  6     def __init__(self, face, suit):
```

----> 7         self.face = face

```
  8         self.suit = suit

  9
```

AttributeError: can't set attribute

**then i was like ok since i only defined the getters not setters** but why is the object created successfully through the following class without the error **since the class also creates Card object** here's the second class code

```
import random
from card import Card #to import the previous class
class DeckOfCards:
     NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52 # constant number of Cards
      def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the deck."""
          self._current_card = 0
          self._deck = []

          for count in range(DeckOfCards.NUMBER_OF_CARDS):
              self._deck.append(Card(Card.FACES[count % 13],
               Card.SUITS[count // 13]))
```

***as you can see the see the second class also generates the Card object but i was confused, how is that possible without the preceeding error??? ***

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. The most likely explanation is that you aren't actually using the same class

Comment: It was not created successfully, you have only defined the class, but if you actually go create the DeckOfCards object, you get the same error.

Comment: ok let me create DeckOfCards object, and see

Comment: Yes I got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up your attribute name a little bit, in your `__init__`, you have `self.face` and `self.suit` as attribute, and in your class, you also defined getter which has the same name AND using attributes `self._face` and `self._suit` which are nowhere defined in your init. You can simply fix it by changing your init to:

```
def __init__(self, face, suit):
    self._face = face
    self._suit = suit
```

Likely your other methods are affected as well, I believe you can fix them by yourself.

Comment: Or you coudl create the setters, but almost certainly, `property` isn't even what the OP should be using

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's right, but that's beyond the scope of this question. I made minimal changes to the code to make it work.